# Intent inside if-else for different activities for different user roles

Tags: java, android-studio, if-statement, android-intent

I am developing a project where there are two types of users : Admin and a basic user. With a simple logic i differentiate them, i.e, in database, I store is_admin value = 1 for admins and 0 for other users.

I have two activity view for that, "AdminViewAcivity" and "UserViewActivty". I need to switch to AdminViewActivity if is_admin=1 and UserViewActivity if is_admin=0.
FYI, in database I gave boolean for this, but it automatically converted to tinyint. So, I'm passing int for that.

Here is the code I tried:

```
if(success){
    String name= jsonResponse.getString("name");
    Intent intent;
    int is_admin = jsonResponse.getInt("is_admin");
    if (is_admin == 1) {
        intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, AdminViewActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("name", name);
        LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, UserViewActivity.class);
        LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intent1);
    }
```

jsonResponse is a JSONObject.

Earlier it was (which worked):

```
if(success){
   String name= jsonResponse.getString("name");
   Intent intent;
     intent=new Intent(LoginActivity.this, AdminViewActivity.class);
     intent.putExtra("name", name);
     LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
```

It will be helpful if there was any other way around.

Comment: your question is unclear, what is the value of `jsonResponse` and `is_admin `

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Sorry for any inconvenience caused. I need this help for completing my project. I have edited the question to address your query, @Pavneet_Singh

Answer (score 0):

Hooray.. I found out why it wasn't working. If anyone has the same issue, please check in your php file whether the order of the parameters are same as in database. Thanks a lot.